# Faking the URL previewer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I appologize if I'm not using the correct terminology, here's the image of what I'm trying to duplicate:

[image]

When you hover over a link you get a little url preview pop up in the bottom corner of your browser.

I implemented some modals on my website, and whenever you hover over the links this little bottom url previewer doesn't fire.

Is there anyway to fake that url preview when you hover over something that's not an actual link? I want my users to know that they can click these things beyond the pointer cursor.

Comment: The "URL previewer" is called the "status bar" (it used to be visible at all times in older browsers, now in modern ones, it's auto-hidden).  In older browsers, you could set [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.status) to put whatever you wanted in the status bar.  This feature is removed in modern browsers.  So no, the only way to trigger it is to use a "real link", an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Just use an anchor tag rather than a button. If you really wanted, you could style said anchor tag to look like a button.

Comment: I am using an <a> tag. I'm using javascript to fire a modal when clicked, but since it doesn't link to a url and is fired via the specified ID it doesn't show the status bar.

Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex: To make it show the status bar, give the `<a>` tag an `href` attribute.  If you don't want the browser to go there, then just prevent the action with `e.preventDefault` in your event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "status bar" will only appear when hovering over `<a>` tags that have an `href` attribute on them.  Adding the `href` attribute will make the status bar appear.

If you are using JavaScript to bind an `onclick` event to the link, just simply use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the browser from following the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="link" target="_blank">Go to Google ?</a>

<script>
    document.getElementById("link").onclick = function () {
        window.open(
            "https://stackoverflow.com/");
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions with just a code snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.